# Delete ldap attribute by keycloak

Tags: ldap, openldap, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm evaluating keycloak for identity management using an existing (open)ldap server.

I've managed to get the `telephoneNumber` ldap attribute into keycloak.

The problem occurs if I try to remove a telephone number via keycloak: keycloak tries to set the ldap attribute to an empty string, which is not allowed. Is there a way to configure the `user-attribute-ldap-mapper` to delete the attribute if its empty?

Best wishes

Daniel

[edit] I've opend a [bug report at keyloak for this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5117)

Comment: It should be trying to set it to null. Submit a bug report.

Comment: As `telephoneNumber` is multivalued it could work if it tries to set it to an empty array

Comment: @Esteban No, it should set it to null. All LDAP attributes are multi-valued unless specifically described otherwise in their schema syntax.